# Extracting first name and last name in Python

Tags: python, regex, extract

I'm trying to extract all the first names AND the last names (ex: John Johnson) in a big text (about 20 pages).

I used split with `\.` as separator and there is my regular expression:

```
\b([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s{1})([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)\b
```

Unfortunately, I only get all the lines of my text instead of only the first names and last names:

```
Suddenly, Mary Poppins flew away with her umbrella
Later in the day, John.... bla bla bla
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What does `[nsregularexpression]` have to do with Python?

Comment: Might have some problems with that regex, for example: `Then John went..`, `If Mary had thought`

Comment: Indeed... and if this is Python... how are you calling/utilising the regex... (which won't only retrieve proper nouns, but we'll come to that later i guess...)

Comment: What do you mean by splitting with `.` as separator? `.` means any character, and your task seems to be searching, not splitting. What's the input you provide to the regex you mention? Directly using `re.search` on the pattern and sentence you mention does identify the name as `("Mary ", "Poppins")`.

Comment: Note that `{1}` is implicit; `\s` and `\s{1}` both match just one character.

Comment: What are your rules for defining name and surname? What we must expect them to be like? All names and surnames start with capital or surnames are all capital? How do you plan to separate a name or surname from a word that is the first word after a comma or at the beginning of a sentence (hence starts with a capital)?

Comment: I suggest reading http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ and then giving up.

Comment: Powerranger, [your regex works fine for me](http://regexr.com?37ft3). @FallenAngel, fyi, words after a comma should not be capitalised (unless they are proper nouns).

Comment: @Powerrangers mistyped word, not comma, I mean dot (or exclamation mark or question mark)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
regex = re.compile("\b([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+) ([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)\b")
string = """Suddenly, Mary Poppins flew away with her umbrella
Later in the day, John Johnson did something."""
regex.findall(string)
```

The output I got was:

```
[(u'Mary', u'Poppins'), (u'John', u'Johnson')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted one regular expression that can handle accents and dash for composed names:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
r = re.compile('([A-Z]\w+(?=[\s\-][A-Z])(?:[\s\-][A-Z]\w+)+)',
           re.UNICODE)
tests = {
    u'Jean Vincent Placé': u'Jean Vincent Placé est un excellent donneur de leçons',
    u'Giovanni Delle Bande Nere': u'In quest\'anno Giovanni Delle Bande Nere ha avuto tre momenti di gloria',
    # Here 'BDFL' may not be whished
    u'BDFL Guido Van Rossum': u'Nobody hacks Python like BDFL Guido Van Rossum because he created it'
}
for expected, s in tests.iteritems():
    match = r.search(s)
    assert(match is not None)
    extracted = match.group(0)
    print expected
    print extracted
    assert(expected == match.group(0))
```